# Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device

Tags: boot, 19.10

I'm running three operating systems in one laptop. The first one is Windows and the other two are Linux. Ubuntu showed this error when booting:

Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
/dev/sda6: clean, 266194/18317312 files, 4971930/73240320 blocks

After getting this error Ubuntu started to lag.

Answer (score 6):

I just had a similar issue on an ubuntu only system. I solved it with

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: In my case, `find /boot/vmli*` listed 5 available kernels and `uname -r` showed my system uses ``5.13.0-27-generic``.  `update-initramfs -u` will only update the **latest** kernel, I needed `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Comment: This answer fixed my Debian 12.5 after setting up zram.

Answer (score 0):

Simply running `update-initramfs`, even on all kernels was not enough for me. My own solution was to add `noresume` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`  and run `sudo update-grub`.

I also removed the `mdadm` package, but I am not sure that this is needed with the `noresume` option.